# open _rels/.rels: permission denied golang

Tags: go

I was trying to unzip a .docx file. First file of name "[Content_Types].xml" has been extracted. But then I encountered an error as follows:

open frontend/uploads/doc_data/_rels/.rels: permission denied

How can we set permission for this?

The unzip function I use is as follows:

```
func Unzip(src, dest string) error {
   r, err := zip.OpenReader(src)
   if err != nil {
       return err
   }
   defer r.Close()
   for _, f := range r.File {
       rc, err := f.Open()
       if err != nil {
           return err
       }
       defer rc.Close()
       fpath := filepath.Join(dest, f.Name)
       if f.FileInfo().IsDir() {
           os.MkdirAll(fpath, f.Mode())
       } else {
           var fdir string
           if lastIndex := strings.LastIndex(fpath,string(os.PathSeparator)); lastIndex > -1 {
               fdir = fpath[:lastIndex]
           }
           err = os.MkdirAll(fdir, f.Mode())
           if err != nil {
               log.Fatal(err)
               return err
           }
           f, err := os.OpenFile(
               fpath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, f.Mode())
           if err != nil {
               return err
           }
           defer f.Close()
           _, err = io.Copy(f, rc)
           if err != nil {
               return err
           }
       }
   }
   return nil
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the Chmod function of the os package to set the file permissions to something that allows you to do what you want.

```
 err := os.Chmod("file.txt", 0777)
 if err != nil {
     fmt.Println(err)
 }
```

more info here : https://socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-change-file-read-or-write-permission-example

Comment: Thanks. The problem was not with the file it was with the folder creation. I used your instructions to set permission for the folder and it solved the issue.